# django-registration 1.0 with Django 1.6 and Python 3.3.4

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm trying to upgrade a webapp called courses from Django 1.4 to 1.6 with django-registration 1.0. None of the other django-registration threads seem to have anything relating to this problem.

I'm running unit-tests via python manage.py test courses which crashes with the following trace:

```
> /home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py(449)commit_on_success()
-> warnings.warn("commit_on_success is deprecated in favor of atomic.",
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 145, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 107, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 279, in setup_databases
    verbosity, autoclobber=not interactive)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 339, in create_test_db
    load_initial_data=False)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 28, in <module>
    class RegistrationManager(models.Manager):
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 94, in RegistrationManager
    create_inactive_user = transaction.commit_on_success(create_inactive_user)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 449, in commit_on_success
    warnings.warn("commit_on_success is deprecated in favor of atomic.",
PendingDeprecationWarning: commit_on_success is deprecated in favor of atomic.
```

I dropped into a pdb session from /home/chris/.virtualenvs/blanket/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py(449)commit_on_success(). Stepping up two stack frames, this has been called from line 28 of site-packages/registration/models.py(28) -> class RegistrationManager(models.Manager)

Has anyone else tried to use django-registration 1.0 with Django 1.6 and seen this failure?

Here is the settings/ directory for reference:
base.py:

```
# Django settings for EduDuck project.

import os
import django
from django.conf import global_settings

DEBUG = False

#get the path name to prepend to other settings
DJANGO_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(django.__file__))

SITE_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                         os.path.pardir, 
                                         os.path.pardir)

# User Profile model 
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'bio.Bio'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/courses/'

# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/?from=olddocs
SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'core.context_processors.git_branch_render',
    'core.context_processors.show_survey_link',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'EduDuck.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'EduDuck.wsgi.application'

#TODO: Ensure templates aren't under docroot for production version
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

#django-registration https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration
#This allows new users 7 days to activate new accounts
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
#Set following to False to disable registration.
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',

    #Temporarily disabling haystack - 'six' package/bundled conflict?
    #django-haystack via elasticsearch backend
    #'haystack',

    #following provides account activation via email via django-registration
    'registration',

    #eduduck apps
    'courses',
    'quiz',
    'support',
    'bio',
    'interaction',
    'outcome',
    'attachment',
)

# See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#simple
# and override this in staging.py and production.py
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
#this is only here since I can't get python manage.py to read this config (handled via wsgi)
#use via python manage.py rebuild_index --using='forcron'
    'forcron': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
            },
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
            },
        },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        },
#TODO uncomment when on Django 1.5
#        'require_debug_true': {
#            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'
#        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'log_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/eduduck.log',
            'maxBytes': 10*2**20, #10 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'log_filedb': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/eduduck_db.log',
            'maxBytes': 10*2**20, #10 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['log_file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['log_filedb', 'console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

and dev.py

```
#settings/dev.py
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = 'INVALID_EXPRESSION: %s'

#django-registration needs an MTA. For development just use console
#smtp is the default, so in prod.py, EMAIL_BACKEND is commented out or missing
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

#INSTALLED_APPS += ("debug_toolbar", )
#INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1", )
#MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ("debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'ed_dev',
        'USER': 'ed_dev',                    
        'PASSWORD': 'quickquackquock',                 
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
# following is for resyncing database on staging server (would be better to 
# get python manage.py to read the staging.py config, as opposed to having this here.
#    'mysql_sync': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
#        'HOST': '',
#   'NAME': 'eduduck',
#   'USER': 'put it back if you need to resync',
#   'PORT': '2369',
#   'PASSWORD': "put it back if you need to resync",
#        'OPTIONS': {
#            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
#        },
#    },
}

#Not very secret SECRET_KEY. Just for dev. Staging and prod. use env var.
SECRET_KEY = 'paranoid'

# Fixture Directory - for development purposes, reloading test data
# after changes to models.
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'fixtures/')
)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-registration doesn't support Python 3.
Use django-allauth instead.

You can find much about django-allauth here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-allauth

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry for delay in accepting your answer.

Comment: Also consider python-social-auth.